# TypeScript: Declaring a callable type as a class method type

Tags: typescript

I have a callable type alias or interface such as

```
type MyCallable = (n: number) => string
```

Then I have a class and one of its methods is of that callable type:

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod(n: number): string {
    return ''
  }
}
```

I want instead to declare its typing using that `MyCallable` type:

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod(n): MyCallable {
    return ''
  }
}
```

Obviously this approach doesn't work because `myMethod` doesn't *return* a `MyCallable`, but *is* itself a `MyCallable`.

Is this even possible in TS?

Comment: Only if you use initializers instead of method sugar. `class MyClass {
  myMethod: MyCallable = ()=>{
    return ''
  }
}` Can't you just make it an interface instead?

Comment: @JuanMendes yeah, I can't do that because that method uses a `MethodDecorator`, and I have no equivalent `PropertyDecorator`. Too specific a case, I know

Answer (score 3):

A slightly wordy way is to declare and implement an interface:

```
type MyCallable = (n: number) => string

type WithCallable = { 
    myMethod: MyCallable
}
class MyClass implements WithCallable {
  myMethod(n) {
    return ''
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd be a bit easier to understand with  an interface right? `interface MyMethodCallable{ myMethod: MyCallable}`

Comment: I don't have the teaching experience necessary to answer that question. They both seem easy enough to me. If you do, feel free to make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
type MyCallable = (n: number) => string;

class MyClass {
  myMethod: MyCallable = (n) => {
    return "";
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Top answer is wrong, because here you will have n:any [screenshot from ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyyo5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).